# Infinite scroll does not work with jquerymobile.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, infinite-scroll

I need infinite scroll with my jquery mobile project. My infinite scroll code work well but when I added jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js to my page the infinite scroll does not work.

This is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            alert("it works");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: when i remove jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js it works but i need it....you can see here the problem with drag scroll   http://m.yazilimsozluk.com

Answer (score 2):

**This should work:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() + 1 >= $('body').height() - $(window).height()) {
  console.log("infinite scroll works"); 
 }
```

});